# Pandas Groupby replace values in decremental order

Tags: python, pandas, replace, pandas-groupby

how can i replace the values in a column in a decremental order with maximum value of the second column is retained and other values are decremented by one from this value for a particular group in pandas?

I have a dataframe with 2 columns A and B

Input :

A                                                           B

210                                                         2
210                                                         1
210                                                         5
210                                                         3
145                                                         1
145                                                         3
145                                                         3
145                                                         6

desired output:

A                                                           B

210                                                         2
210                                                         3
210                                                         4
210                                                         5
145                                                         3
145                                                         4
145                                                         5
145                                                         6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) 
and then you can add the difference between the **maximum** and the group **size** using `groupby.transform`:

```
groups = df.groupby('A').B
df['B']=( groups.cumcount()
                .add(1)
                .add(groups.transform('max')
                           .sub(groups.transform('size')) )
        )
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     A  B
0  210  2
1  210  3
2  210  4
3  210  5
4  145  3
5  145  4
6  145  5
7  145  6
```

**Time comparision**

```
%%timeit
groups = df.groupby('A').B
df['B']=( groups.cumcount()
                .add(1)
                .add(groups.transform('max')
                           .sub(groups.transform('size')))
        )
#3.33 ms ± 66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
def custom_f(grp):
  m = grp.max()
  return np.arange(m - grp.shape[0]+1 , m+1)
df['B'] = df[['A','B']].groupby('A').transform(custom_f)
#9.18 ms ± 890 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. Basically, we are creating a range for each group and the range goes from `max - num_rows + 1` to `m`.

```
def custom_f(grp):
  m = grp.max()
  return np.arange(m - grp.shape[0]+1 , m+1)
df['B'] = df[['A','B']].groupby('A').transform(custom_f)
```